# Java AsynchronousFileChannel with lots of open file handlers in Linux

Tags: java, linux

My understanding of asynch file I/O might be wrong but I am trying to use the latest JDK 7's AsynchronousFileChannel to speed up an application with an unexpected worse result. The application was using synch mode with PrintWriter before I made the change as below:

```
    if( asynchMode ){
        AsynchronousFileChannel writer = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get(outputFileName),
        StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);       
        ((AsynchronousFileChannel)writer).write(ByteBuffer.wrap(builder.toString().getBytes()), 0);
    else{
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try{
            writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            outputFileName)));
            ((PrintWriter)writer).write(builder.toString());
        }
        finally{
            if( null!=writer )
                writer.close();
        }
    }
```

The above code resides in a class of its own. The variable `asynchMode` allows me change the behaviour of the program. As the application writes alot of files which really need not be further validated, I would rather not let the CPU idle and the thread wait while the files are being written. The above is based on my understanding of asynch file I/O which I admit maybe on a wrong footing.

One strange thing besides poorer performance is that there is alot of file descriptors when I do a `ls -l /proc/p`.
Thanks for any clarifications and help!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you don't close the file, in the second case you do.

I would make sure you are testing only the thing you are interested in.  Otherwise it could be that adding getByte() which you only do in the first case is the cause of the delay.  I suggest you start with a byte[] before you start the timer in both cases for a like, for like comparison.

Note: If you have one block of data/text using a buffered stream/writer only added overhead at best.

When it comes to writing real files, it is the writing of the data to disk which is the bottle neck.  Your system can copy data at many GB/s but most spinning disks can only sustain writes 50-100 MB/s.  So making it slightly more efficient in Java might not give you the results you want.

Comment: Actually, I guess my expectations of the JDK 7's asynchronous file I/O is perhaps unrealistic. If you look at my code above you can see that no handlers had been passed and the asynch file channel instance is immediately out-of-scope after the if statement. I didn't use the close() method because I realize that files were not written completely or not at all if I call the close() method immediately after the write(...) method. However, it seems like all the asynch file channels (and the underlying file descriptors in Linux) are not closed until the JVM exit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a potential time bomb as the could be many, many FDs opened and each FD could contain a huge buffer of contents causing the java application to hold up lots of unnecessary resources. My initial expectation was that the GC will take care of removing the file channel instances as well as the underlying FDs by flushing out the file contents and closing the FDs. Guess it is back to square one for me i.e. asynch file IO not useful for my scenario. Thanks.